# sql split string into always same amount of pieces

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, user-defined-functions

I Need to split a string into pieces using a deliminiter (for example ,)

In any case I need same Number of chunks, if text is too short the function should return empty strings.

I would like to store this as a Scalar function as that is better to use it where needed in compare to table-value function.

I am Looking for a function like myFunction (inputstring, chunknumber)

for example: Inputstring = abc, def, ghi

expected sample results:

myFunction (inputstring, 1)  -->  'abc'

myFunction (inputstring, 3)  -->  'ghi'

myFunction (inputstring, 5)  -->  ''

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: In what world is a scalar function better than a table valued function? Assuming your table function is inline ( a single statement) it will be WAY faster than a scalar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use the following User Defined Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[myFunction]
(   
    @String         VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @ChunkNumber    INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR (100)  
AS
BEGIN     
    DECLARE @Incrementer AS INT = 1;   
    DECLARE @SliceValue VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) = ',';
    DECLARE @ReturnObject AS VARCHAR (100) = '';
    DECLARE @SplitedValues TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, Item VARCHAR (100));

    IF LEN(@String) < 1 OR @String IS NULL  
        RETURN @ReturnObject   

    WHILE @Incrementer != 0     
    BEGIN     
        SET @Incrementer = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String);

        IF @Incrementer != 0     
            SET @SliceValue = LEFT(@String, @Incrementer - 1)     
        ELSE     
            SET @SliceValue = @String     

        IF(LEN(@SliceValue) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @SplitedValues(Item) VALUES (@SliceValue)     

        SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @Incrementer)     
        IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK     
    END 

    SELECT @ReturnObject = Item FROM @SplitedValues WHERE Id = @ChunkNumber;

RETURN @ReturnObject  

END
```

Sample execution:

```
SELECT [dbo].[myFunction] ('abc, def, ghi', 5) -- returns empty
SELECT [dbo].[myFunction] ('abc, def, ghi', 3) -- returns ghi
SELECT [dbo].[myFunction] ('abc, def, ghi', 1) -- returns abc
```

Comment: Using a loop for a splitter is probably the worst possible way to do this. There are so many set based splitters that will blow the doors off this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where a set based splitter that return the position number is critical. Thankfully Jeff Moden has such a splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

The code for his splitter is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Now for your case you want another function. No problem we can leverage his splitter for this. But we are also going to need a tally table. Hopefully you have one of these but if not here is the one I used. I keep it as a view because it so useful and this is lightning fast. This technique I first learned about from Jeff Moden also.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we can actually get to creating your new function. It is pretty straight forward with these two other components in place.

```
create function GetChunkValue
(
    @Inputstring varchar(100)
    , @ChunkNumber int
) returns table as
    return
    select ChunkValue = isnull(s.Item, '')
    from cteTally t
    left join dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Inputstring, ',') s on s.ItemNumber = t.N
    where t.N = @ChunkNumber
```

And finally here is some example code using it.

```
select *
from GetChunkValue('abc, def, ghi', 2)
```